# Store result in a variable of dynamic query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

instead of executing the query I want the result in a variable

```
set @countdata = createtb
```

please help and sorry for the bad English

delimiter

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@% PROCEDURE proc_tbl_exam_given_ext_test11_first(
    IN get_mock_test_id VARCHAR(255),
    IN get_user_id int(11),
    IN get_question_id int(11),
    IN get_answered TEXT charset utf8,
    IN get_current_datetime DATETIME,
    IN get_exam_in_language VARCHAR(50),
    IN get_exam_type CHAR(1),
    IN get_subject INT,
    IN get_chapter INT,
    IN get_timetaken INT, 
    IN get_email_first char(1)
)
BEGIN

    -- DECLARE ext_table_name varchar(255);
    -- set ext_table_name =  concat('tbl_exam_given_ext_',get_email_first); 

    SET @answergiven2 = CONCAT( "SELECT count(*) as total FROM tbl_exam_given_ext_",get_email_first, " WHERE mock_test_id= '", get_mock_test_id, "' AND user_id = ", get_user_id, " AND question_id = ", get_question_id);
    PREPARE createtb FROM @answergiven2 ; 
     EXECUTE createtb ; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE createtb ;
    -- select @answergiven2; 

END;
```

this code is giving the output but I want to store in a variable to perform another task in the same procedure

Comment: Select..INTO.. perhaps

Comment: Can you please explain more  Thank you